# Does SuperUser (from koush) work on 4.4.2?

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung, superuser

I've installed update.zip (from download.clockworkmod.com) via the recovery, /system/xbin/su file exists:

```
$ ls -l /system/xbin/su                                     
-rwsr-sr-x root     root       311872 2015-12-28 00:28 su
```

But it doesn't work:

```
shell@lt033g:/ $ su
255|shell@lt033g:/ $ id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=1003(graphics),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:shell:s0
shell@lt033g:/ $
```

Why? I'm using Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014, Android 4.4.2

P.S. I can not use SuperSU for some reasons, I can use SuperUser only.

Comment: Is it related: https://github.com/koush/Superuser/issues/253 ?

Comment: What specifically  is the problem with using [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu&hl=en)?

Comment: @Firelord license.

Comment: I see. Are you fine with compiling your own su binary? The guy [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/124857) did that from the source available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/su/)