# How to flash /system using twrp when system.img is 1.7GB and internal storage has 1.5GB max limit

Tags: rom-flashing, internal-storage, twrp, partitions, system

I happen to have an old phone laying around with messed up system partition(a couple of files accidentally deleted). This phone has an internal storage of max 1.5 GB(total 4gb, after setting everything up leaves me with 1.5 GB). I downloaded the stock firmware for the phone and the system.img size is almost 1.7GB I have twrp recovery. Is it possible to flash with an external sdcard.
N.B: I unfortunately don't have my pc with me atm.

Comment: It would help if you could tell us what phone (manufacturer, model) this is. Apart from that: no worries about the size, `/system` is not "internat storage" but a different partition – which is one reason why only 1.5G are "left" from the 4G announced (the remaining ~800M are on the other partitions, like recovery, cache etc).

Comment: Yes you can flash from SD card. There must be some free space out of 1.7GB, so you can put it in an archive to reduce size. Or expose `system` partirion through UMS to a PC and flash image there. Or stream the image over network (using adb/nc) and write to partition at the same time. There are even more possibilities.

Comment: @Irfan Latif, hey, turns out I can only flash boot partition using twrp, guess I'll have to settle for the pc then. I also came across this that it can be done with `dd` command as well. Like `dd if=/storage/sdcard/system.img of=I forgot the name` from twrp terminal. is that possible

Comment: Yes. `dd` is the most commonly used tool in Linux world to read and write raw partitions. The methods I mentioned above are meant to be combined with `dd`  to solve the problem of space shortage.

Comment: [`dd` — Linux manual page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html)

Comment: Yep, I know about `dd` disk dump, but am confused about the of=? directory as in where should I dump the contents to, at which directory. An idea just popped in my head, what if I extracted the files in system.img and replaced everything under `/` to the contents of the files from image. Isn't that the same thing as doing dd?

Comment: Sorry, the link I mentioned earlier was suppossed to be this https://android.stackexchange.com/a/125422/332427

Comment: See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526) to know how you find correct block device. The answer is about `userdata` partition. Replace that with `system`.

Comment: Yep! found it in `/dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/by-name/system` I did a ls -l on system and found that it is a symbolic link to `/dev/block/mmcblk0p20` Now, should I do `dd if=/storage/sdcard0/system.img of=/dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/by-name/system` or should I do `dd if=/storage/sdcard0/system.img of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p20` Which one should I do?

Comment: This idea also popped in my head, the stock rom was in a zip file. Is it possible to flash the entire thing using twrp? That would be super easy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113104/discussion-between-silly-goose-and-irfan-latif).